# Handling touch in two diffent views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I Have two views(scrollview and topview) on a window each of frame (0,0,320,480),

```
[window addsubview:scrollview];
[window addsubview:topview];
```

In **scrollview** i am doing zooming,pinching operation and in **topview** view i have placed some buttons. My problem is i want to handle touches to both views like user can do pinching in scrollview and also he must be able to press buttons on topview. ( I am not adding topview on scrollview because these buttons are fixed if i add they also scroll).

I am getting touches to only one view at a time. How to handle touches to both subviews any idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you having in top view? only buttons?

If yes, then remove them from top view and place them directly on to the window and bring them to front.

Comment: Instead of adding directly to window, I added a view above window and in that i placed both scrollview and buttons. It solved my problem( If i click of button it will respond otherwise control goes to scrollView)